# Angular 2 and Ionic 2 - how to make them work and should I even bother?

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular2-services

I've been trying to develop a glossary app in Ionic 2 and when I got to using the http service, it all went to hell. Angular 2 tutorials were changed, the mock server couldn't be set up, and Ionic 2 documentation wasn't of much help. I tried updating dependencies to latest versions, to try to build things according to the newest tutorials, but I couldn't make that work either because some of the classes required throughout the code just weren't getting exported anywhere.

Would you recommend waiting until everyone catches up with one another, or just trying to continue the development with older versions? How am I supposed to make all this work?

Answer (score 1):

Since Ionic 2 builds upon Angular 2 it seems viable to suggest to just wait for Ionic 2 to integrate the final version of Angular 2, if youre not working on a production app right now.

The latest beta of Ionic uses Rc4 of Angular 2,but rumors say the RC version of Ionic is just around the corner with AngularConnect event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting really frustrated here, but I guess I will have to wait, or just give up Ionic 2 and go over to building just with Angular 2.

Comment: That's the price you pay for being an early adopter. Since ng2 final is out I suppose is just a matter of weeks before Ionic 2 final comes out as well.